# pgsql query : value with quote at first character

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I need to build a postgreSQL query in js :

```
var value = "something";
var query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('" + value + "')";
```

Since the variable "value" can contains quotes, I doubled all quotes by modifying my original code as well :

```
var value = "something with quotes maybe";
var query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('" + value.replace("'", "''") + "')";
```

It works fine for most cases except if the string value start with a quote.
How to resolve the "quote problem" if the quote is the first character of the value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is much more to escaping quote characters, see [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Depending on the Javascript/Postgres library, you're using, there might be some SQL string escape function, you can use.

The real solution though, would be to use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), which eliminates this problem altogether.

I don't know, if such a Javascript/Postgres library exists. But if there is one, your statement would become something like this (this is mainly modeled after how it looks like in languages like PHP or Java)

```
var value = "something with quotes maybe";
var sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (?)";
var stmt = conn.prepare(sql);
stmt.execute(value);
```

---

Looking at [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) and at [Parameterized queries and Prepared Statements](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Parameterized-queries-and-Prepared-Statements), this would be

```
var value = "something with quotes maybe";
var sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ($1)";
client.query(sql, [value]);
```

Comment: Thanks you ! I'didn't know about prepared statments.
Works fine :)